# Understanding network aliases in Linux

Tags: ifconfig, iproute

When I already have an IPv4 address on interface and I try to add a second one with `ifconfig eth0 192.168.8.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` command, then my previous IP address is replaced. I can add second address with for example `ifconfig eth0:test 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` command. This creates so called alias. However, I could also add secondary IP address with `ip addr add 192.168.12.0/24 dev eth0` command and this does not create alias:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:be:05:21:22:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.1/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.10.1/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eth0:test
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.12.0/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Are both configurations are exactly the same simply `ip addr` way doesn't create this unnecessary alias?

Comment: AFAIK latter is the newer and recommended method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ip-address(8)`:

> It is possible to have several different addresses attached to one device.
>   These addresses are not discriminated, so that the term alias is not quite
>   appropriate for them and we do not use it in this document.

You can, however, emulate the deprecated “alias” functionality
using labels:

```
$ ip address add dev eth7 42.42.42.42/23 label eth7:foo
```

Comment: Am I correct that `label` is nothing more than a short description for secondary IP address?

Comment: Can you please describe what the different parameters are doing? That would improve the answer. Thank you.